# Create a nice plot with parallel axis in Python from a highdimensional dataset in the form of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, plot

I have a highdimensional dataset in the form of a numpy matrix. I want to plot my data using parallel axis. Also, I later want to be able to add some highlighted data to the plot. I would like to create a legend and name the axis manually. Example code would be very great since I am a python beginner.

I have already tried using pandas but that didn't work like I would like since I didn't find a way to work with a numpy matrix in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=60, learning_rate=200)

X_embedding = tsne.fit_transform(x)

## if x is a sparse matrix you need to pass it as X_embedding = tsne.fit_transform(x.toarray()) , .toarray() will convert the sparse matrix into dense matrix

for_tsne = np.hstack((X_embedding, y.values.reshape(-1,1)))
for_tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(data=for_tsne, columns=['Dimension_x','Dimension_y','Score'])

## colors = {0:'red', 1:'green'}

## plt.scatter(for_tsne_df['Dimension_x'], for_tsne_df['Dimension_y'], c=for_tsne_df['Score'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))

sns.FacetGrid(for_tsne_df, hue='Score',height=6).map(plt.scatter,"Dimension_x","Dimension_y").add_legend()
plt.title('TSNE with TFIDF encoding of project_title feature with perplexity=60')
plt.show()